# Loading icons with transparency to tray menu of application

Tags: c++, image, winapi

I need the icons of application menu options had no background. I'm using this code to set icons to menu options:

```
HICON PowerIcon = (HICON)LoadImageA(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCEA(POWERBTN),IMAGE_ICON,24,24,LR_LOADTRANSPARENT);
HICON ResetIcon = (HICON)LoadImageA(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCEA(RESETBTN),IMAGE_ICON,24,24,LR_LOADTRANSPARENT);
//    HICON PowerIcon = LoadIconA(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCEA(POWERBTN));
//    HICON ResetIcon = LoadIconA(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCEA(RESETBTN));
ICONINFO PowerII, ResetII;
GetIconInfo(PowerIcon, &PowerII);
GetIconInfo(ResetIcon, &ResetII);
HBITMAP PB = PowerII.hbmColor;
HBITMAP RB = ResetII.hbmColor;
SetMenuItemBitmaps(PopupMenu, TRAY_EXIT, MF_BYCOMMAND, PB, PB);
SetMenuItemBitmaps(PopupMenu, TRAY_RESTART, MF_BYCOMMAND, RB, RB);
```

And the result is... with black background:

[image: buttons]

I don't need this background.

**How to draw this icons in menu as is, without background?**

Comment: are this 32bpp images with alpha ?

Comment: @RbMm, I don't know exactly how does WinAPI process icon when loading to handle. This is regular *.ico with transparent background.

Comment: but icon internal containing several bitmaps - are this 32bpp ?

Comment: The color depth is 32

Comment: this good worked with 32bpp bitmaps (not icon) loaded with `LR_CREATEDIBSECTION` flag

Comment: @RbMm, well... I created RGBA bmp files with GIMP, but can't see the images at all. I tried to use  LoadBitmapA and (HBITMAP)LoadImageA with flag you suggested. Should I render them manualy?

Comment: in my test `LoadImage( , IMAGE_BITMAP, .. LR_CREATEDIBSECTION)` work well. i use it in `MENUITEMINFO` with `hbmpItem` or `hbmpUnchecked` - work well only when `LR_CREATEDIBSECTION` set. and of course must be 32bpp with alpha channel (not all 0 or 255)

Comment: for example this code correct display transparent bitmap - `if (HMENU hmenu = CreatePopupMenu())
   {
    MENUITEMINFO mii = { sizeof(mii), MIIM_ID|MIIM_STRING|MIIM_BITMAP , 0, 0, 
     id, 0, 0, 0, 0, L"demo", 0, 
     (HBITMAP)LoadImage(0, L"***.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION|LR_LOADFROMFILE)
    };
    InsertMenuItem(hmenu, 0, TRUE, &mii);
    TrackPopupMenu(hmenu, 0, *, *, 0, hwnd, 0);
    DeleteObject(mii.hbmpItem);
    DestroyMenu(hmenu);
   }` but if remove `LR_CREATEDIBSECTION` transparent breaked

Comment: @RbMm, I can't load image at all in this way. If to load from file - error 1814, MAKEINTRESOURCE - error 87. WTF??? All names are correct

Comment: I use `LR_LOADFROMFILE` because for test use external .bmp file. if you have image in resource - remove flag `LR_LOADFROMFILE` and use correct *hinst* (usually `(HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase` ) and resource name

Comment: @RbMm, `HBITMAP Img = LoadBitmapA(0,MAKEINTRESOURCEA(RESETBTN));` - error 87. In .rc file - `RESETBTN BITMAP "reset.bmp"`, defined `#define RESETBTN 1004`. Why error?

Comment: why hinst == 0? because this and error

Comment: @RbMm, does not matter. `LoadBitmapA(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCEA(RESETBTN))` - error 87

Comment: why not `LoadImage` use ? in any case `LoadBitmap` not excepted in this case because I say that you need call LoadImage and specify LR_CREATEDIBSECTION to create a DIB section.

Comment: @RbMm, I tried to do according to your advice, but after this errors I tried to simplify to see what happens with hbitmap... Error is the same. Just can't load an image

Comment: are hinst is correct ?

Comment: @RbMm, yes. I use it in `WNDCLASSEXA` to set tray icon which resource is also recorded in .rc... and the app has this icon in tray

Comment: if you even `LoadBitmap` can not success call, I don't know

Comment: @RbMm, the problem was in .bmp file created by GIMP. After resaving an image in mspaint the HBITMAP is correct ))

Comment: @RbMm, I used a program "Pixelformer" to create 32 bit bitmap file. Seems that damn GIMP makes 32 bit bmp unreadable for WinAPI. So your code works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

menu transparent display DIB section bitmap rather than a compatible bitmap. best and most easy choice - use 32bpp bitmaps created via `LoadImage( , IMAGE_BITMAP, .. LR_CREATEDIBSECTION)`. try for test bitmap (in menu) created with and without `LR_CREATEDIBSECTION` flag and view different.

if you have icon in resource instead of bitmap, in my test `GetIconInfo` return not DIB section bitmap and if not transparently displayed. possibly way - yourself create DIB section bitmap from icon resource, instead use LoadIcon + GetIconInfo.

```
HBITMAP CreateDIBfromIcon(PCWSTR lpName, int cxDesired, int cyDesired)
{
    union {
        PVOID pv;
        PBYTE pb;
        PBITMAPINFOHEADER pbih;
    };

    if (HRSRC hrs = FindResource((HMODULE)&__ImageBase, lpName, RT_GROUP_ICON))
    {
        if (pv = LoadResource((HMODULE)&__ImageBase, hrs))
        {
            if (int i = LookupIconIdFromDirectoryEx(pb, TRUE, cxDesired, cyDesired, 0))
            {
                if (hrs = FindResource((HMODULE)&__ImageBase, MAKEINTRESOURCE(i), RT_ICON))
                {
                    if (pv = LoadResource((HMODULE)&__ImageBase, hrs))
                    {
                        if (pbih->biBitCount == 32)
                        {
                            BITMAPINFOHEADER bih = *pbih;
                            bih.biHeight >>= 1;
                            PVOID pvBits;

                            if (HBITMAP hbmpItem = CreateDIBSection(0, (PBITMAPINFO)&bih, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &pvBits, 0, 0))
                            {
                                memcpy(pvBits, pb + pbih->biSize, 4*pbih->biWidth*pbih->biHeight);
                                return hbmpItem;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

in your case need use 
`CreateDIBfromIcon(MAKEINTRESOURCE(POWERBTN), 24, 24)` and `CreateDIBfromIcon(MAKEINTRESOURCE(RESETBTN), 24, 24)`